# I am trying to figure out how to create a user within a method

Tags: java, methods, new-operator

I have a method:

```
public User(String name) {
        //create a user with the appropriate name}
```

I want to create something where if someone types in

```
User (bob);
```

an instance of the user class with the name "bob" will appear.

I tried to use this code:

```
public User(String name) {
User name = new User();
```

but I am getting errors that state the the constructor User(); is undefined and also that there is a duplicate local variable name. I know this is a basic question, but I can't seem to figure it out and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to invest in a Java book for beginners. It will explain constructors.

Comment: Post your entire `User` class

Comment: `public User(String name){ }` is either a constructor or it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

The first bit of code you have is a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), not a [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).  It exists to tell Java how to create your class when using the `new` keyword.

You likely want to do this:

```
public class User{
    private String name; 
    public User(String n){
        name = n; // When creating my User, give him this name
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

That defines your `User` class.  Now you can create one anywhere

```
public class MyApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args){
          User user = new User("Tom");
          System.out.println(user.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have 
`private String name;`
`public User (String name){`
`}`

does anything go in the brackets?

Comment: `name=n;` is between the braces (braces = { } , brackets = [ ] ).  Keep in mind Java is ***not*** whitespace delimited.   While you can create a new `User` in the constructor, I don't think that's what you want to do.  Please try reading the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) if you are still confused.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I followed what you were asking for... but this might be it. As some of the comments mention, I would highly recommend picking up a good beginner Java programming book to better grasp the basics of constructors.

```
public User(String inName) {
    name = inName;
}
//...
new User("Bob");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
User name = new User("yourname");
```

Then add a constructor with a string parameter.